# roots with strictly negative real part

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the equation $$\lambda+1-\alpha e^{-\lambda\tau}=0\;,$$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\tau>0$. I need to establish conditions on the parameters $\alpha$ and $\tau$ so that the given equation has only roots $\lambda$ such that $\mbox{Re}(\lambda)<0$. Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: note that $\left| e^{-\lambda \tau}\right| = e^{-\tau \text{Re}(\lambda)}$.